# How can I create a view border that looks pencil sketched in Swift?

Tags: swift, view, border

For example, something like this:

[image: border with pencil sketch style]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Such way with `UIColor.init(patternImage:UIImage)`

```
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 20
self.imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: UIImage(named: "images.jpeg")!).cgColor
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

[image]

here is pattern image [Pattern](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/357121445435760067/)